# Logstash 7.5 on docker log4j vulnerability

Tags: docker-compose, centos, logstash

5 on docker (docker-compose) and I need to remove a class with this command:
 `zip -q -d <LOGSTASH_HOME>/logstash-core/**/*/log4j-core-2.* org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class`

the problem is that inside the container zip command is not installed.

How can I install the command inside docker?

and if I can install and use the command, every time I restart de container I have to use that command?